# My text and image as plane are visible in the viewport but aren't rendering but my background Video is visible in both. Why?

Tags: text-object

I've selected the viewable camera and render options in the collections tab for my text but when I render it, the text is completely gone
Same goes for any image I import as planes to the project. Nothing renders except for the background video. Is the problem due to the video or what am I missing here?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5UP4.jpg